# Pages are not searchable by Google anymore

Tags: search, 7

After migrating my Drupal website to WebHosting, I noticed that my pages aren't searchable by Google. It finds nothing, even though it should clearly find my website. Same thing happens when I want to know the ranking of my website. I haven't used the Pathauto module yet, but I think it should find the domain main page at least.

Do you know where the fault could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has the old IP address and DNS been deleted?

Can you provide a bit more information please? Is the site being crawled by any search bots? Check the reports/recent hits file. Is your sitemap downloadable in Google Webmaster Tools? If so, when was it last downloaded/crawled?

Without knowing a few of those things above its difficult to say, but check the following also:

- If you had previously specified geographic targeting in google webmaster tools, make sure that the new IP address resolves to the same geographic zone.
- Check in Google Webmaster Tools whether you specified "www" in front of your domain name, and check the rewrite rules in .htaccess or your server config files. If you have the Pathauto/Nodewords modules installed, start by checking the canonical URLs in your page source code, checking that they match against the sitemap.

In response to your other questions:
navigate to [ YOURDOMAIN**/admin/reports/hits ] when logged into drupal. Here you will see recent hits. Clicking on each one will show you the date, time and page that was visited and importantly the IP address. You can then check these using an IP lookup service. Normally googles crawler starts with an IP of [ 66.*.**.*** ].

when search engines look up a website, they look up the IP address first. Check the old IP address, if you still have it, using a tool such as ip-lookup which is a web page where you can check where an IP address resolves to.

When you open your GWT account you can tell google to return your site without the www, but this isn't likely to be the problem.

You'll see from the recent hits report whether google has crawled your site, this in turn tells you whether it is likely to be available yet in Google Webmaster Tools. You should follow the setup instructions google provides to open a GWT account, its straightforward.

you haven't changed the .htaccess file which in most cases is fine. However, depending on you system setup you may need to. From what you've said I expect its a basic setup without any additional server rules such as caching and rewrites. By the way, if you want to provide your web site address I'll look into it for Ya!

Comment: ` has the old IP ... deleted?` what do you mean by this?

Comment: where should I find `reports/recent` file?

Comment: Where can I find if my site is downloadable by Google Webmaster tools?

Comment: My domain name is without `www`

Comment: I haven't changed the Drupal default `.htaccess` file.

Comment: My Drupal web hasn't this `YOURDOMAIN*/admin/reports/hits` URL, it has only `/admin/reports/dblog` . I can't see there the google's IP.

Comment: you only have ../hits hen you enable the statistics module

Answer (score 2):

Check your root folder for a robots.txt file. Using Google Webmaster Tools you can test this; see [Block or remove pages using a robots.txt file](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449&from=40364&rd=1).

Comment: The default robot.txt file that comes with Drupal doesn't block the  search bots from looking into the node pages.

Comment: but maybe he copied the robots.txt from his old site

Comment: His old site was already using Drupal; the OP just changed hosting provider.

Comment: your right, I misread, but still no harm in checking if the right robots file is in place. Probably it was better just to comment.

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/AijTi2kb) is my robots.txt file. I havent' changed it. I haven't changed hosting provider, but from localhost to hosting provider.

Comment: can you post your url?

Comment: how long ago did you put the site online?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Metatag to add lots of rich meta data to the pages, and XMLSitemap to notify the search engines that the content is available & updated. Other useful modules include Site Verify (http://drupal.org/project/site_verify) to add the necessary meta tags / files to inform several search engines that your site legit. Also, have lots of good content :-)